Typing in a form field initially loses focus, but works fine when typing in again
In my project, I made some Components to universally handle the displaying and updating of some objects. Each row has a column called "actions" where the user can click an icon and a dialog will open where the user can update the object. One of the objects is the customer and their addresses. All UI components are from the shadcn library
Let's start from the base, the FormField. This by default renders a simple Input field. If instead a children is provided, it either renders it as it is with some props, or if it's a Function Component it creates an element and injects its needed props. It's useful if I need more than a simple Input field.
import {
  FormField as Field,
  FormControl,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";

type FormFieldProps = {
  control: Control<any>;
  name: string;
  label: string;
  example?: string;
  children?:
    | ComponentType<{
        field: ControllerRenderProps;
        className?: string;
        onBlur?: () => void;
        onKeyDown: (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => void;
      }>
    | ReactElement;
  type?: string;
  handleKeyDown?: (e: KeyboardEvent) => void; // used for a custom focus handling
  className?: string;
  ref?: RefObject<any>;
  autofocus?: boolean;
};

export default function FormField({
  control,
  name,
  label,
  example,
  children,
  handleKeyDown,
  className,
  type = "text",
  autofocus = false,
  ref,
}: FormFieldProps) {
  return (
    <Field
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field }) => {
        return (
          <FormItem className="w-full">
            <FormLabel>
              {label}
              {example && (
                <>
                  {" "}
                  <span className="text-muted-foreground">{example}</span>
                </>
              )}
            </FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              {children ? (
                typeof children === "function" ? (
                  React.createElement(children, {
                    field,
                    className,
                    onBlur: () => {},
                    onKeyDown: (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
                      if (handleKeyDown) {
                        handleKeyDown(e);
                      }
                    },
                  })
                ) : (
                  React.cloneElement(children as ReactElement, {
                    ...field,
                    ref,
                    onBlur: () => {},
                    onKeyDown: (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
                      if (handleKeyDown) {
                        handleKeyDown(e);
                      }
                    },
                  })
                )
              ) : (
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  onBlur={() => {}}
                  type={type}
                  ref={ref}
                  autoFocus={autofocus}
                  className={className}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (handleKeyDown) {
                      handleKeyDown(e);
                    }
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </FormControl>
            <FormMessage />
          </FormItem>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

Then we have "FormFields", which is responsible for rendering the fields based on a given layout. As you can see, if the formField.unique == true I will give the children the "field" prop which contains mainly the value of that field and the function to change said value
export type FormFieldType = {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  type?: HTMLInputTypeAttribute;
  children?: ComponentType<{ field: ControllerRenderProps }> | ReactElement;
  unique?: boolean;
  className?: string;
};

interface FormFieldsProps<T> {
  formSchema: z.ZodType<Partial<T>>;
  defaultValues?: DefaultValues<T>;
  formFields: FormFieldType[];
  handleSubmit: (values: Partial<T>) => void;
  footerName: string;
  layout: { fieldsPerRow: number }[];
}

export default function FormFields<T extends Partial<T>>({
  handleSubmit,
  footerName,
  formSchema,
  defaultValues,
  formFields,
  layout,
}: FormFieldsProps<T>) {
  const form = getForm<T>(formSchema, defaultValues);
  const onSubmit = (values: Partial<T>) => {
    handleSubmit(values);
  };

  let fieldIndex = 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
          {layout.map((row, rowIndex) => {
            const rowFields = formFields.slice(fieldIndex, fieldIndex + row.fieldsPerRow);
            fieldIndex += row.fieldsPerRow;

            return (
              <div key={rowIndex} className="flex gap-4">
                {rowFields.map((formField, index) => {
                  return !formField.children ? (
                    <FormField
                      key={index}
                      control={form.control}
                      name={formField.name}
                      label={formField.label}
                      type={formField.type}
                      className={formField.className}
                    />
                  ) : formField.unique == true ? (
                    <FormField
                      key={index}
                      control={form.control}
                      name={formField.name}
                      label={formField.label}
                      type={formField.type}
                      className={formField.className}
                    >
                      {({ field }) => {
                        return React.createElement(
                          formField.children as ComponentType<{
                            field: ControllerRenderProps;
                          }>,
                          { field }
                        );
                      }}
                    </FormField>
                  ) : (
                    <FormField
                      key={index}
                      control={form.control}
                      name={formField.name}
                      label={formField.label}
                      type={formField.type}
                      className={formField.className}
                    >
                      {formField.children as ReactElement}
                    </FormField>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}

          <div className="flex w-full">
            <DialogFooter className="w-full">
              <Button type="submit" className="w-full">
                {footerName}
              </Button>
            </DialogFooter>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function getForm<T>(
  formSchema: z.ZodType<Partial<T>>,
  defaultValues?: DefaultValues<Partial<T>>
) {
  return useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });
}

Then we have "Manager", the Component which handles the various actions (add, update and toggle) and renders the actual table
interface ManagerProps<T extends { id: number; active: boolean }> {
  receivedData: T[];
  path: string;
  fetchActions: ActionsType;
  FormFields: ComponentType<FormFieldsProps<T>>;
  columns: ColumnDef<T>[];
}

interface FormFieldsProps<T extends { id: number; active: boolean }> {
  handleSubmit: (values: Partial<T>) => void;
  footerName: string;
  object?: T;
}

export default function Manager<T extends { id: number; active: boolean }>({
  receivedData,
  path,
  fetchActions,
  columns,
  FormFields,
}: ManagerProps<T>) {
  const [globalFilter, setGlobalFilter] = useGlobalFilter();
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>(receivedData);
  const [onlyActive, setOnlyActive] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const triggerIcons = (disabled: boolean) => {
    return {
      delete: disabled ? "Attiva" : "Disattiva",
      update: <Pencil size={24} className="hover:cursor-pointer" />,
      add: <Plus size={24} className="hover:cursor-pointer" />,
    };
  };

  const handleToggle = (objectToToggle: T) => {...};

  const handleUpdate = (newValues: Partial<T>, objectToUpdate: T) => {...};

  const handleAdd = (values: Partial<T>) => {...};

  const getTrigger = (action: "delete" | "update" | "add", disabled: boolean = false) => (
    <Button type="button">{triggerIcons(disabled)[action]}</Button>
  );

  const actions = {
    edit: ({ object }: { object: T }) => (
      <DialogWrapper title="Modifica elemento" trigger={getTrigger("update")} variant="delete">
        <FormFields
          object={object}
          handleSubmit={(values) => handleUpdate(values, object)}
          footerName="Modifica"
        />
      </DialogWrapper>
    ),
    delete: ({ object }: { object: T }) => (
      <DialogWrapper
        title="Attenzione!"
        trigger={getTrigger("delete", !object.active)}
        variant="delete"
        onDelete={() => handleToggle(object)}
      >
        <div>
          Stai per <b>{object.active ? "disattivare" : "attivare"}</b> questo elemento. Sei sicuro?
        </div>
      </DialogWrapper>
    ),
    add: (
      <DialogWrapper title="Aggiungi elemento" trigger={getTrigger("add")}>
        <FormFields handleSubmit={handleAdd} footerName="Aggiungi" />
      </DialogWrapper>
    ),
  };

  // getColumns basically return an array of columns with the "columns" prop + the action
  // column I mentioned
  const tableColumns = getColumns<T>(columns, actions.edit, actions.delete);
  const table = getTable({
    data: onlyActive ? data.filter((item) => item.active) : data,
    columns: tableColumns,
    globalFilter,
    setGlobalFilter,
  });

  return (
    <div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-4">
      <TableControls
        table={table}
        AddComponent={actions.add}
        globalFilter={globalFilter}
        setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
      >
        <div className="space-x-2 flex items-center ml-auto">
          <Checkbox
            checked={onlyActive}
            onCheckedChange={() => {
              setOnlyActive(!onlyActive);
            }}
          />
          <Label className="text-xl">Solo attivi?</Label>
        </div>
      </TableControls>

      <Table<T> table={table} />
    </div>
  );
}

Finally we have "CustomerDashboard", the actual component that creates the fields and the layout and feeds them to the Manager:
type FormValues = Partial<CustomerWithDetails>;

export default function CustomersDashboard() {
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<CustomerWithDetails[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRequest<CustomerWithDetails[]>("GET", "/api/customers/", "getCustomersWithDetails").then(
      (customers) => {
        setCustomers(customers);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  const Fields = ({
    handleSubmit,
    object,
    footerName,
  }: {
    handleSubmit: (values: FormValues) => void;
    object?: CustomerWithDetails;
    footerName: string;
  }) => (
    <FormFields
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      footerName={footerName}
      defaultValues={{ ...object }}
      layout={[{ fieldsPerRow: 2 }, { fieldsPerRow: 2 }, { fieldsPerRow: 1 }, { fieldsPerRow: 1 }]}
      formFields={getCustomerFields()}
      formSchema={formSchema}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
      <div className="w-[90%] h-[90%] flex max-h-[90%] gap-4">
        {loading ? (
          <div className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center ">
            <Image src={logo} alt="logo" width={600} height={600} className="animate-spin" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Manager<CustomerWithDetails>
            receivedData={customers}
            columns={columns}
            FormFields={Fields}
            path="/api/customers/"
            fetchActions={{
              add: "",
              toggle: "",
              update: "",
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>

      <GoBack path="/backend" />
    </div>
  );
}

export const formSchema = z.object({
  // ... other fields
  addresses: z.any(),
});

export function getCustomerFields(): FormFieldType[] {
  return [
    // ... other fields
    {
      name: "addresses",
      label: "Indirizzi",
      unique: true,
      children: ({ field }: { field: ControllerRenderProps }) => {
        return <CustomerAddresses field={field} />;
      },
    },
  ];
}

As you can see I'm using "CustomerAddresses", a Component to handle the addresses. It uses an Accordion, stacking every address so when I open one, some fields appears where I can edit the address data. It has a field prop rappreseting the actual form field holding the value and the function to change said value:
export default function CustomerAddresses({ field }: { field: ControllerRenderProps }) {
  const [currentAddresses, setCurrentAddresses] = useState<Address[]>(field.value ?? []);

  const debouncedOnChange = useCallback(
    debounce((newAddresses) => {
      field.onChange(newAddresses);
    }, 500),
    [field]
  );

  const updateField = (addressId: number, key: keyof Address, value: any) => {
    const newAddresses = currentAddresses.map((address) => {
      if (address.id === addressId) {
        if (key === "street") {
          const { street, civic } = parseAddress(value);
          return { ...address, street, civic };
        } else {
          return { ...address, [key]: value };
        }
      }
      return address;
    });

    setCurrentAddresses(newAddresses);
    debouncedOnChange(newAddresses);
  };

  return (
    <Accordion
      ref={field.ref}
      type="single"
      collapsible
      className="max-h-96 w-[40vw] overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden pr-6"
    >
      {currentAddresses.length > 0 ? (
        currentAddresses.map((address) => (
          <AccordionItem value={address.id.toString()} key={address.id}>
            <AccordionTrigger>{address.street + " " + address.civic}</AccordionTrigger>
            <AccordionContent className="space-y-8">
              <div className="space-y-2">
                <Label>Campanello</Label>
                  <Input
                    defaultValue={address.doorbell?.toString()}
                    onChange={(e) => updateField(address.id, "doorbell", e.target.value)}
                  />
              </div>

              // all the other fields...
            </AccordionContent>
          </AccordionItem>
        ))
      ) : (
        {...}
      )}
    </Accordion>
  );
}

The correct behaviour of this Component would be to render each Accordion address item and, when a random item is pressed and one of its fields changed, update the local state and call field.onChange(updatedAddresses) to reflect the changes on the form.
It almost works except for the onChange function part. The moment I type something, for example, in the doorbell field, after the debounce delay the accordion closes and for some reason, the focus goes to the Dialog. When I re-open the same address, I will see it updated with the new doorbell, and if I start typing again on the doorbell field (or any other field), everything works fine and no unexpected closings.
After some testing, the same thing occurs when instead of having something "complex" like an Accordion, I use a simple select and below the fields. I select an address, fields get filled in with the address data, and when I start typing the field loses focus after the debounce delay, select resets to nothing and the focus goes to the dialog. Then I try to type again on the same address and same field (or any field), and everything works.
I tried not using the debounce delay and the same problem arises. onChange fires correctly and it does its job, but for some reasons it messes up my components rendering.
This only happens when using a children and unique is true. It's almost like the first onChange will trigger a re-render of everything (?) and that messes up my Component. In all other cases, I can type freely on the inputs and everything works.
I'm lost. I don't know if it's a default behaviour of my form library, my Components tree or something I don't know about React. This is really bothering me because I'm this close to completing my customers/addresses part of the project. I tried everything (although if the solution is one of those please I would still love the code): refs, useMemo, memo or weird props passing shenanigans, but nothing. Even trying to remember which item was opened was futile, the first typing on a field will always result in a sort of "re-render" which breaks everything. Afterwards, everything works as expected. Maybe it's the way I'm injecting/passing the field prop? Maybe a rendering issue with the keys?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!
